# iPhone - Sending comments, images, and/or video to website using JSON

Tags: iphone, json, service, web

I need to be able to pull comments/images/video down from a website and allow the user's comments/images/videos to be pushed to the website.  I am pretty sure JSON can be used to do this for text, but I'm not sure if it can be used for images/video.

Can it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON only supports a few simple data types (strings, booleans, numbers). In order to include more rich media formats, you'd have to determine how to serialize them into this simple data types.

Consider parsing them down into a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), or hosting them elsewhere, and linking back to them via a URL.

- [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501699/data-url-png-from-uiimage) has information on how to convert a UIImage into a data URI.
- You could also use `NSData`'s initializers to get the raw data of a video resource.

Answer (score 1):

You can but as the other poster stated this is not good idea, get the Image URLs via JSON.
For uploading you want to use POST so you can stream data directly. This saves the serialization and memory when uploading large files. look at: [AFNetworking Uploading a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234186/afnetworking-uploading-a-file)